# Why is "not" faster than "bool()" in Python (or, speed of Python functions vs. statements)?

Tags: python

I made an interesting observation the other day.  I was experimenting with various ways to get the "truthiness" of an object and the speed of each, and I noticed that `not` is *much* faster than `bool`.

```
>>> bool([5, 6, 7])
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>> not not [5, 6, 7]
True
>>> not not []
False
>>> import timeit
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('bool(a)', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.19072036743164061
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('bool(a)', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.18562331199645996
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('not not a', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.072056698799133304
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('not not a', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.073475956916809082
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('not a', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.043941426277160647
>>> mean(timeit.repeat('not a', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.044287109375000001
```

We can see that using the `bool` function is significantly slower than using the `not` statement, even though ultimately they do the same thing (return the boolean state of the object). Now, we have all been told that in Python the function overhead is large, but I was not expecting this type of discrepancy in this case for the following reasons:

- `bool()` is a builtin function, meaning that it is written in C, and I would have expected this to have a rather low overhead
- In both cases, Python has to assess the "truthiness" of the object internally (I would imagine they use the same C routines to do this internally)

  - In fact, `not` has to return the logical *opposite* of the object's "truthiness", so in theory it is doing a bit more work (but perhaps there is an implementation detail that gets around this)

In my mind, because both functions are doing essentially the same thing all the extra time must be coming from the function overhead.  If that is the case, why is it that a statement is able to avoid so much overhead compared to a function? If it is not the overhead, why is `bool()` so much slower than `not`?

---

UPDATE:  Here are also the min times in addition to the mean.

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat('bool(a)', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.18180489540100098
>>> min(timeit.repeat('bool(a)', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.1821761131286621
>>> min(timeit.repeat('not not a', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.0707249641418457
>>> min(timeit.repeat('not not a', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.07100605964660645
>>> min(timeit.repeat('not a', 'a = [5, 6, 7]', repeat=10))
0.04264092445373535
>>> min(timeit.repeat('not a', 'a = []', repeat=10))
0.04357004165649414
```

Comment: Reversing the way one branches on a comparison does not take any more time than it would in the other direction -- if you know assembly, think about `je` vs `jne`; they're both just one instruction.

Comment: ...beyond that, think about what a function call _does_ -- there's a ton of stack mangling involved.

Comment: I don't know assembly, but that makes sense.  It still doesn't explain the speed difference, though :)

Comment: Repeating this `10` times won't give a significant result. Regarding the overhead, you could check the disassemblies of those calls using Python's `dis` module and compare. I'd guess that `not a` doesn't actually create a new `PyObject`.

Comment: I suggest learning assembly. Understanding the overhead involved in even a C function call would make the leap from there to grokking the overhead of a function call in an interpreted language with exception support clear, bordering on obvious. :)

Comment: Are you implying that the factor of 10 difference is within the noise?

Comment: @filmor, ...well, if `bool()` does the sane thing and returns one of two interned constants, it's not necessarily pulling memory off the heap.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, it does that. But still, `bool()` is a function call.

Comment: @filmor, `repeat` does the operation 10000 times, then repeats that 10 times, so it is much more than 10 times.

Comment: @filmor, never said it didn't, was just responding to the "actually create a new PyObject". Though if Python stack frames are instantiated as objects before they're needed to represent an exception (an implementation detail I have no idea about), that would be some extra object-creation overhead there as well.

Comment: @SethMMorton Note however that the mean of the times is not necessarily meaningful. The minimum may do a better job of removing noise.

Comment: Without even decompiling the Python byte code, the answer to this seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @martineau Then please enlighten us with your own answer.

Comment: Function call overhead.

Answer (score 5):

(This is not supposed to be an answer, just documentation): These are the byte code sequences of the given expressions:

`bool(a)`:

```
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (bool)
            3 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
            6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
            9 RETURN_VALUE
```

`not a`:

```
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
            3 UNARY_NOT
            4 RETURN_VALUE
```

`not not a`:

```
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
            3 UNARY_NOT
            4 UNARY_NOT
            5 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: So clearly `UNARY_NOT` is more efficient than `CALL_FUNCTION`.  But as @delnan pointed out, both have to call the `__bool__` method of the object to determine the boolean value.  So, what extra stuff is the `bool` call doing that `UNARY_NOT` is not?

Comment: Well, `bool` is called as a Python function and introduces an additional lookup in `globals`. Note, that each operation here on it's own is extremely cheap, so this could be the significant difference.

Comment: Hmm, on my machine the expression `bool(True)` evaluates exactly as fast as `bool(a)`, `bool` evaluates only marginally slower than `not a`, so `CALL_FUNCTION` is actually the "problem" here.

Answer (score 2):

All function calls have significant overhead -- you're creating a new stack frame to hold the new locals you have within your call, after all.

If this were a more expensive operation, that overhead would get lost in the noise. Since you're looking at such a trivial operation, it stands out.

Comment: Why can the `not` statement get around that overhead?

Comment: @SethMMorton, ...because it operates within the existing stack frame.

Comment: Because it is a special byte code operation (`UNARY_NOT`).

Comment: (1) `bool` and the `__bool__` methods of the types tested here are written in C, so no Python frame is created, only a C function call which is dirt cheap (in the order of nanoseconds). (2) `not` also has to call the `__bool__` method, so it's one call vs two calls, not no calls vs one call.