# Check if an array contains any element of another array in Python

Tags: python

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 1]
```

I need to check if one (or more) elements are common in both arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the intersections of the sets and get the boolean:

```
>>> bool(set(a) & set(b))
True
>>>
```

Or `not not`:

```
>>> not not (set(a) & set(b))
True
>>>
```

Or just with `any`:

```
>>> any(i in b for i in a)
True
>>>
```

Comment: The `not not` seems ridiculous when you can just convert it to a bool.

Comment: @rkechols Actually it's faster than `bool` :)

Comment: @rkechols Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594231/why-is-not-faster-than-bool-in-python-or-speed-of-python-functions-vs-s) out.

Comment: But it obscures the purpose of the code. If you're going for speed, you shouldn't be using python.

Comment: @rkechols yeah, that's true

Answer (score 0):

this is simple intersection concept which we used to learn in maths well here I have tried to demonstrate the function which take common from two list and return new list with common elements

```
    def intersection(lst1, lst2):
        lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
        return lst3
    
    
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 1]
    
    print(intersection(a,b))
```