# How to create a 2D list in python based on values in another 2D list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have a 2D list (or list of lists):

```
[[1,0,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [0,0,0]]
```

How can I iterate this list and and convert all values to boolean for example:

```
    [[True,False,True],
     [True,True,True],
     [False,False,False]]
```

Using comprehensions instead of for loops would be ideal.

Retaining the old data isn't necessary but it may be simpler to just create a new set.

Comment: Time for the good old [not not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25594231/14277722): `[[not not y for y in x] for x in a]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list comprehension replace for loop in 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345770/list-comprehension-replace-for-loop-in-2d-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Nested for loops is the best I could come up with :/

You would just change the values in the array.

```
l= [[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[i])):
        if l[i][j] == 1:
            l[i][j] = True
        else:
            l[i][j] = False
```

output: [[True, False, True], [True, True, True], [False, False, False]]

Comment: First of all, the question specifically asks for a list-comprehension. Second, that `if/else` is really an overkill` - just do `bool(l[i][j])`...

Answer (score 0):

Is a nested list comprehension what you are looking for?

```py
[[bool(inner_entry) for inner_entry in inner_list] for inner_list in outer_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```py
x = [[1, 0, 1], 
     [1, 1, 1], 
     [0, 0, 0]]

y = [[bool(i) for i in x] for x in x]
print(y)
```

the output is:

```py
>>> [[True, False, True], [True, True, True], [False, False, False]]
```

Comment: Actually, you are right. The solution wasn't efficient as I wasn't using `a`. I have updated my solution.